# Grub Legacy - Auto select boot option

Tags: linux

When booting I am presented with a Grub option list consisting of two entries

```
Gentoo Linux x.x.x
Gentoo Linux x.x.x.(rescue)

The highlighted entry will be booted automatically in 30 seconds.
```

How can I configure this to automatically boot into the first?
If not possible, is there a way to lower the timer to 1 or 2 seconds?

Ideally I would only want to be presented with this screen if a failed start up occurred previously, otherwise skipping this screen and going straight into the system

Comment: from memory this file is /boot/grub/menu.lst, but it can't be automatically edited on start faillure.

Comment: @Archemar Correct, added default 0 timeout 0 does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In legacy versions of GRUB you'd simply set the `default` and `timeout` variables within the file `/etc/grub.conf`, so that they corresponded to the kernel stanza that you wanted to default to, and the length of time in seconds that you wanted GRUB to wait.

**NOTE:** The stanzas are numbered, starting with 0.

**Example**

Here's part of my file from CentOS 5, but it should give you an idea of what to do.

```
$ sudo more /etc/grub.conf 
# grub.conf generated by anaconda
#
# Note that you do not have to rerun grub after making changes to this file
# NOTICE:  You have a /boot partition.  This means that
#          all kernel and initrd paths are relative to /boot/, eg.
#          root (hd0,4)
#          kernel /vmlinuz-version ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00
#          initrd /initrd-version.img
#boot=/dev/sda
default=1
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,4)/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-348.3.1.el5.centos.plus)
    root (hd0,4)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-348.3.1.el5.centos.plus ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-348.3.1.el5.centos.plus.img
title CentOS (2.6.18-274.18.1.el5.centos.plus)
    root (hd0,4)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.18-274.18.1.el5.centos.plus ro root=/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 rhgb quiet
    initrd /initrd-2.6.18-274.18.1.el5.centos.plus.img
```

Notice that I'm defaulting to stanza #1 in the above example!